Why `[1, 2, 3]` is not showing as an `Array(3)` in Console?
When I inspect an instance of an array (like const arr = [1, 2, 3];), the prototype chain for that array will point to Array.prototype.

However, I am not able to understand why Array.prototype is displayed as an empty array (Array(0)) in Chrome console.log()?


I have gone through post1 and post2 but still not able to understand this basic concept.

Why [1, 2, 3] in the console in not showing as an Array(3)?


Have you hovered over the small [i] with reddish background?

Array(0) here refers to the [[Prototype]] value, i.e. to Array.prototype.
For instance if you log
const obj = {
  arr: [1, 2, 3]
}

You can see that the actual Array in the arr property is logged as Array(3), but that the [[Prototype]] of this Array is marked as an empty Array.

That's because, like I pointed to you in your now deleted question, Array.prototype is actually an Array itself. See this Q/A for more details.
So if you do something like
Array.prototype[2] = "bar";
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

The Array's Prototype will now say Array(3).

thanks for the explanation. I have one doubt here.  const arr = [1, 2, 3]; console.log(arr);  Here, why console log is not showing Array (3)? Instead it is just showing (3)

Because that's how they display an Array when it's set as a direct argument to log(). I agree it's quite surprising, given that other list objects list Set or Map do show the constructor, but it's probably to remove noise when logging lots of such common objects. But you shouldn't read much into it but a choice they made.  They can very well decide to change that in a future version.

When you inspect [1, 2, 3] in the console, you are inspecting the instance of the array, which is Array(3) because it has 3 elements.
Array.prototype, however is an empty array itself (Array(0)), and that's what is displayed when you inspect the prototype of any array instance.
Array.prototype contains all the methods not the instance of the element.
Hope you get it, of not then do let me know.

Array.prototype is an empty array-like object that provides methods and properties to all array instances, but it doesn't hold actual array elements. That's why it appears as Array(0) when you inspect it in the console. The array you create, like [1, 2, 3], is a separate instance and is displayed with its elements (Array(3) in this case).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
